# session not working properly in php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have a session problem in my Laravel project when uploaded on hostgator server. The session driver is a file type issue. When I try to login I set global session like `session(['user'=>1,'username'=>'zee']`)

When I am redirected to another route and try to access session values  the session is empty. Before redirecting if I `print_r(session('user'));` the value printed means working fine on the same controller.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
use App\User;
use Validator;
use Session;

class userLoginController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function user_login(Request $request)
    {
       if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')]))
           {
                   $user = Auth::user(); 
                   $request->session()->put('aa_key', 'value');
                     session(['user' => $user->name,'user_data'=>$user->id]);

                   return redirect()->route('user_dashboard')->with(['user_data'=>1]);
          }
          return redirect()->route('all');
    }



use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
use App\User;
use Validator;
use Session;

class userLoginController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function user_login(Request $request)
    {
       if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')]))
           {
                   $user = Auth::user(); 
                   $request->session()->put('aa_key', 'value');
                     session(['user' => $user->name,'user_data'=>$user->id]);

                   return redirect()->route('user_dashboard')->with(['user_data'=>1]);
          }
          return redirect()->route('all');
    }
}
```

**another controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
use App\post;
use App\category;
use App\subcategory;
use App\attribute;
use App\attribute_value;
use App\post_attribute;
use App\midea;
use App\User;
use App\like; 
use App\rating; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Redirect;
use Session;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class FrontController extends Controller   public function userdashboard(Request $request)
    {
          $flg = session('user_data');
          $ad =Session::get('aa_user');
          //dd($flg);
          print_r($ad);
          exit;
    }
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/userlogin', 'userLoginController@user_login'); 

Route::get('/user_dashboard', 'FrontController@userdashboard')->name('user_dashboard');
```

Answer (score 0):

use Session facade instead of session()
Example :

```
Session::put('key', 'value');
```

get value from session

```
Session::get('key');
```

Comment: Session::get('key'); also still there problem

Comment: its workig fine on local and on godaddy server when am upload my project on hostgator server then session not wokr properly

Comment: Are you using API middleware?

Comment: ok just delete cache directory inside bootstrap directory and create new directory named cache

Comment: ok just delete cache directory inside bootstrap directory and create new directory named cache   ok

Comment: am delete cache directory and create new directory named cache  but problem not solve

Comment: Are you using API middleware? no